# Why does my js cause the last image of the array to appear before navigating to the view?

Tags: javascript, debugging

As of now, my code successfully goes from one image to another upon clicking on it.

However, the issue I'm facing is that once you get to the last image and click (to redirect user to `indexTwo.html`), it takes the user back to the first image for like 2 seconds and then it redirects to `indexTwo.html`.

My question is: How would I prevent that behavior from happening?  In other words: click through all the images and once the last image's clicked, redirect user to `indexTwo.html` without seeing the first image at all.

Note: I know `if (imageId === 0) {...}` statement is the culprit but not sure how to go about fixing it.

```
let theImage = document.getElementById('the-image');

let index = [
    "http://tech21info.com/admin/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/chrome-logo-200x200.png",
    "https://cdn.tutsplus.com/net/uploads/legacy/155_drupal/200x200.png",
    "https://townandcountryremovals.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/firefox-logo-200x200.png"
];

let op = 1;
let imageId = 0;

let clickedImage = () => {
    // start animation opacity
    if(op === 1) {
        let timer = setInterval(() => {
            if(op <= 0.1) {
                // load the next image
                imageId = (1 + imageId) % index.length;
                theImage.src = index[imageId];

                // reset the opacity
                theImage.style.opacity = op = 1;
                clearInterval(timer);

                if (imageId === 0) {
                    window.location = "indexTwo.html";
                }

            } else {
                op -= 0.1;
                theImage.style.opacity = op;
            }
        }, 50)
    }
};
```

Comment: Why do you use circular increment (`% index.length`) if you don't want it actually? Just remove that, change `if (imageId === 0)..` to `if (imageId >= index.length)..` and move it to the line before `theImage.src`.

Comment: @hindmost ah ok, that works!  but one slight issue that arose is that in my `<img>` tag in my html file, it has an attribute that says `alt="image is down`.  I'm seeing that upon clicking on the last image before `indexTwo.html` renders on the screen.

Comment: That because the code assigning `theImage.src` is executed _**before**_ the page is reloaded. You have to do early return to prevent that. Add `return` inside `if (imageId...` statement.

Comment: @hindmost I tried adding a `return` inside `if (imageId...` but all that did was cause `imageId` to increment infinitely without stopping cause `indexTwo.html` to never get rendered.

Comment: Then place `clearInterval(timer);` before `if (imageId...`. Or use `else` block.

Answer (score 0):

do you need to verify the datatypes match for imageId and the number 0? if not, try using == instead of ===